# How to Update OLEDB-Driver on Windows Server 2016?

Tags: oracle, oledb

How to upgrade OLEDB-Driver (Release 12.2.0.1.0) to 19.10 ?
We get several error messages like "cannot allocate memory" on Windows Server.

Comment: And what makes you think that upgrading the driver will solve the memory problem?

Comment: You an simply update it. It is not possible to have more than one OLEDB driver (per architecture) installed. This is a Windows COM limitation.